# Azure Search index is not updating when I publish changes to my QnAMaker knowledgebase

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-cognitive-search, azure-qna-maker

I have a Microsoft chat bot that is using a QnAMaker knowledgebase that is getting frequently updated due to still being in development.  It seems that updates to pre-existing question and answer pairs are not being propagated in the Azure Search Index when changes in the QnAMaker knowledgebase are published.

What can I do to force the search index to update itself?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just to note, is it updating at any point down the line or does it get stuck in a previous version?

Comment: I think it is stuck.  I did notice the test knowledgebase index is staying up to date, however publishing the QnAMaker again still didn't push the updates over to the production azure search index.

Comment: Try going into your azure search service in the azure portal itself. Go to the "indexers" tab on the table on the overview blade, and try manually running it again. Not sure if this will unstick your service in this case so I'll post this as answer if you confirm it works. (if it does work the next step is to look into the schedule it autoruns)

Comment: It won't let me go to that tab because I haven't created any indexers.  I don't know if creating an indexer would interfere with whatever process the QnA Maker service is using to populate the search index.  I looked at the production instance again, and any new record I entered is getting into the index, it is just when a record is updated that it is not being updated in the production index, just the test index.

Comment: Can you double check that the endpoint you've connected to your bot has not changed after publishing? Occasionally the azure search instance will create another index which changes the keys.

Comment: It hasn't changed.  Also verified that the QnA Maker service has the current key to access the Azure Search service.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting into contact with support for the qna maker team for cases like this, however if you're willing to commit some time and try to do it yourself (if you have a lot of questions) then there is an extreme option that should work to force refresh your search instance.

The steps that worked for me are:

1. Delete your current frozen indexes from the search instance in azure (everything but test).
2. Make an edit to every single QnA pair in your kb (even a blank space at the end of the question works, you just need it to be added for retraining)
3. Retrain/save your kb. (refresh the url-populated questions as well)
4. Publish your knowledge base again.

All the newly edited questions (in this case all of them) should be freshly added to the index. I am sorry that this is a bit of an extreme option though, so I'd still recommend going to support before this generally.